# Tabla JSON marca error

Tags: php, html, mysql, tablas

soy relativamente nuevo en la programación, por lo que espero me apoyen para saber que modificar en las líneas de código para lograr el siguiente resultado:

El programa desarrollado almacena datos de diferentes áreas (por poner un ejemplo) y a su vez tiene diferentes usuarios, los cuales, al momento de logearse obtiene todos los datos registrados de la BD aunque no sean de su área, al principio no le di importancia, pero al momento de visualizar que todos los usuarios pueden ver los datos almacenados busque como filtrar los datos para que solo les muestre los datos correspondientes a su área.

Anexo código de mi tabla para llamar los datos:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('verificarDatos/config.php');
if (isset($_SESSION['email']) != "") 
    $nameUser   = $_SESSION['fullName'];
    $email      = $_SESSION['email'];
    $idUser     = $_SESSION['id'];
    $idArea     = $_SESSION['area'];

?>

<?php
    /*
        * Script:    Tablas multiples con datos del lado del servidor para PHP y MySQL
    */
    
    require 'conexion.php';
    
    /* Nombre de La Tabla */
    $sTabla = "archivomun";
    
    /* Array que contiene los nombres de las columnas de la tabla*/
    /* En esta línea he modificado el código pero no logro obtener el resultado, he usado 
    inner join y el where sin resultados satisfactorios */

    $aColumnas = array('id', 'bdfelaboracion', 'bddependencia', 'bdunidad', 'bdfondo', 'bdnexpediente', 'bdnombre', 'bdufisica');

He usado las siguientes funciones 
     //$aColumnas = array("'id', 'bdfelaboracion' WHERE id_usuario = $idUser");
     //$aColumnas = array(SELECT id, bdfelaboracion, bddependencia, bdunidad, bdfondo, 
      bdnexpediente, bdnombre, bdufisica FROM archivomun WHERE id_usuario = 1);
//$aColumnas = array("SELECT id, bdfelaboracion, bddependencia, bdunidad, bdfondo, bdnexpediente, bdnombre, bdufisica FROM archivomun WHERE bdunidad = '$idArea'"); 

y me muestra el siguiente error:

DataTables warning: table id=mitabla - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

    

    /* columna indexada */
    $sIndexColumn = "id";
    
    // Paginacion
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".$_GET['iDisplayStart'].", ".$_GET['iDisplayLength'];
    }
    
    
    //Ordenacion
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= $aColumnas[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                ".$_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] .", ";
            }
        }
        
        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }
    
    //Filtracion
    $sWhere = "";
    if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumnas[$i]." LIKE '%".$_GET['sSearch']."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }
    
    // Filtrado de columna individual 
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $aColumnas[$i]." LIKE '%".$_GET['sSearch_'.$i]."%' ";
        }
    }
    
    
    //Obtener datos para mostrar SQL queries
    $sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumnas))."
    FROM   $sTabla
    $sWhere
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
    ";
    $rResult = $mysqli->query($sQuery);
    
    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "
    SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
    ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = $mysqli->query($sQuery);
    $aResultFilterTotal = $rResultFilterTotal->fetch_array();
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];
    
    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "
    SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
    FROM   $sTabla
    ";
    $rResultTotal = $mysqli->query($sQuery);
    $aResultTotal = $rResultTotal->fetch_array();
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];
    
    /*
        * Output
    */
    $output = array(
    "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
    "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
    "aaData" => array()
    );
    
    while ( $aRow = $rResult->fetch_array())
    {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $aColumnas[$i] == "version" )
            {
                /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumnas[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumnas[$i] ];
            }
            else if ( $aColumnas[$i] != ' ' )
            {
                /* General output */
                $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumnas[$i] ];
            }
        }
        
        $row[] = "<td><a href='modificar.php?id=".$aRow['id']."'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></a></td>";
        $row[] = "<td><a href='#' data-href='eliminar.php?id=".$aRow['id']."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#confirm-delete'><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></a></td>";
        
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }
    
    echo json_encode( $output );
?>
```

Agradezco todas las orientaciones para lograr el resultado esperado

Comment: Buenas, Omar, ¿puedes incluir la estructura de tus tablas? ¿A qué te refieres con los datos de su area? Da la sensación de que has copiado ese código sin saber muy bien qué hace. A mí me parece un código excesivamente rebuscado preparado para construir dinámicamente búsquedas sobre una única tabla. No parece estar preparado para hacer JOINS. ¿No sería mejor que hicieras el código tú mismo para tus datos específicos y le fueras añadiendo funcionalidad a medida que lo necesites o mediante incrementos sencillos?

Comment: Hola RubioRic, correcto lo qué comentas respecto a lo del código, lo copie de una web para mandar llamar datos de la base datos, he realizado el código y problema resuelto.

Saludos...

Comment: Buenas, Omar, puedes responderte tu mismo y aceptar la respuesta como válida si has solucionado el problema :-)